# What's an equation that describes a circle, with oscillating outline?

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

I'm looking for an equation that describes a circle with oscillating outline. See picture below. Anyone who knows a good way to do that? [image: sketch of the intended result]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can't be a real *function* as there are several $y$ for one $x$.

Comment: A **function**?  It does not pass the vertical line test so it is not a function from $x$ to $y$.  Do you mean for it to be a *parametric function* and have it be a function from $t$ to $(x,y)$?  Or how about a polar function and have it be a function from $\theta$ to $r$?

Comment: A polar equation that is similar, how about $f(\theta) = 1 + \frac{1}{4}\sin(10\theta)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In polar coordinates, add some periodic perturbation to a constant radius. E.g.

$$\rho=R+r\cos(n\theta).$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take, for instance, $\displaystyle\theta\mapsto\left(\cos(\theta)+\frac{\cos(10\theta)}{10},\sin(\theta)+\frac{\sin(10\theta)}{10}\right)$.

Comment: This gives cusps on the inside of the curve, not smooth waving shape that the drawing seems to want.

Answer (score 2):

The parametrisation
$$
\theta\mapsto(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)
$$
gives a circle. Now we want a wavey motion about along circle. Note that the parametrisation
$$
\theta\mapsto\left(\frac{\cos10\theta}{10}, 0\right)
$$
is a curve that goes back and forth along the $x$ axis, so if we rotate it by an angle of $\theta$:
$$
\theta\mapsto \left(\frac{\cos10\theta}{10}\cdot \cos\theta, \frac{\cos10\theta}{10}\cdot\sin\theta\right)
$$
this should give us the a nice radial waving motion when added to our circle.

The full expression that this gives us is
$$
\theta\mapsto\left(\cos\theta + \frac{\cos10\theta}{10}\cdot \cos\theta, \sin\theta + \frac{\cos10\theta}{10}\cdot\sin\theta\right)
$$
which gives the following figure:

[image]

This turns out to be exactly the same curve that some others have suggested by working in polar coordinates, and add a small sine perturbation to a constant radius. You can freely adjust the denominator $10$ to change the oscillation amplitude, or the coefficient $10$ of $\theta$ to change the oscillation frequency.